# Getting PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' on a different tomcat instance

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am getting this exception while hitting my Base URL on a different tomcat instance, but can see the page absolutely fine on the parent tomcat instance.

**Parent tomcat** - Original Tomcat Installation with all the out of the box folders.

**Parallel tomcat** - parallel tomcat instance pointing to the Parent tomcat but has its own server.xml and start and shutdown scripts.

I have gone through all the links discussing this Warning message but none of the solutions mentioned is solving the problem for me.

My configuration -

web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" id="handlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.m.mcp.businessprocess" />
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="order">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layout.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

my tiles layout.xml

```
<definition name="DefaultTemplate" 
  template="/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title"     value="MCP - Business Processes" />
    <put-attribute name="header"    value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="left"      value="" />
    <put-attribute name="right"     value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer"    value="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="searchProcessView" extends="DefaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="left"  
        value="/WEB-INF/view/search_process.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="right" 
        value="/WEB-INF/view/blank_page.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Controller Code -

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/searchProcessView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchProcessView(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("processSearchInput", new ProcessSearchInput());
    return "searchProcessView";
}
```

The messages in the log file -

```
13:20:29.247 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView: name 'searchProcessView'; URL [searchProcessView]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13:20:29.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView - Added model object 'processSearchInput' of type [com.m.mcp.businessprocess.pojos.ProcessSearchInput] to request in view with name 'searchProcessView'
13:20:29.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.processSearchInput' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'searchProcessView'
13:20:29.268 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer - Render request received for definition 'searchProcessView'
13:20:29.276 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/sla_processes/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp]
13:20:29.277 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp
13:20:29.278 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp]
13:20:29.280 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp
13:20:29.281 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp]
13:20:29.283 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp
13:20:29.285 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp]
13:20:29.286 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sla_processes/WEB-INF/view/template/sla_template.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
13:20:29.286 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

So basically my controller is getting invoked and it returns the tiles view name which is being resolved by reading the layout.xml

The problem comes when the template jsp path is being resolved.

I really doubt if it has something to do with the code part, as this runs fine on the parent tomcat but doesn't work with the separate instance of tomcat.

Lastly the structure of my parallel tomcat -

```
bin
   -startup.bat
   -shutdown.bat
conf
   -server.xml
logs
temp
webapps
   -application.war
work
```

I would appreciate any pointers here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found the problem, my prallel tomcat installation setup was missing a file - web.xml.
I added that file from the parent installation and restarted tomcat and i am getting the page now.